# Save clicks to file

Tags: vb.net

I got asked a couple of days ago how to save number of clicks you have done to each button in a program to a small file, to keep track of what is most used. Since it was ages ago i dabbled with visual basic i said i would raise the question here, so here goes.

There are 5 buttons labels Button1-Button5. When a button is clicked it should look for the correct value in a file.txt and add +1 to the value. The file is structured like this.

1. Button1 = 0
2. Button2 = 0
3. Button3 = 0
4. Button4 = 0
5. Button5 = 0

So when button1 is clicked it should open file.txt, look for the line containing Button1 and add +1 to the value and close the file.

I have tried looking for some kind of tutorial on this but have not found it so i'm asking the collective of brains here on Stackoverflow for some guidance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the file structure a must or can you implement it with a different structure? (serialization pops to my mind as an easy way to do it)

Comment: No the file structure is not a must, but it should be easy to read when you open it to view the data.

Comment: Writing a file every single time the user clicks the mouse is exceedingly ugly.  Just write it at program termination.  Collect mouse events with IMessageFilter, use Control.FromHandle() to map the target window handle to a control, store them in a Dictionary(Of Control, Integer).

Comment: Do you need to keep the file between program runs? I mean do you need to append the values to an existing file if there is one, or can you simply overwrite the existing file?

Comment: The file should not be overwritten since it collect data on which option is used the most. It's a small test program that will be converted into ASP.net in the future but first some data is needed and he wanted the option to track this to know which option is used the most. ASP.net version wont have clicktrack, this is just for the testing phase. I'm trying out CristiC777 version and it seems to be working with some bugs which i'm trying to resolve. Mind you it was 12 years ago i used VB. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete file first
new ver ..

```
Imports System.IO.File
Imports System.IO.Path
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

Dim line() As String
Dim strbild As StringBuilder
Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim pathAndFile As String
Dim addLine As System.IO.StreamWriter

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim fileName As String = "myfile.txt"
    Dim appPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    pathAndFile = Path.Combine(appPath, fileName)

    If System.IO.File.Exists(pathAndFile) Then
        'line = File.ReadAllLines(pathAndFile)

    Else
        Dim addLineToFile = System.IO.File.CreateText(pathAndFile)      'Create an empty txt file
        Dim countButtons As Integer = 5                         'add lines with your desired number of buttons
        For i = 1 To countButtons
            addLineToFile.Write("Button" & i & " = 0" & vbNewLine)
        Next

        addLineToFile.Dispose()                                       '  and close file
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    writeToFile(1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    writeToFile(2)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    writeToFile(3)
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    writeToFile(4)
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    writeToFile(5)
End Sub

Public Sub writeToFile(buttonId As Integer)
    Dim tmpButton As String = "Button" & buttonId
    strbild = New StringBuilder

    line = File.ReadAllLines(pathAndFile)
    Dim f As Integer = 0
    For Each lineToedit As String In line
        If InStr(1, lineToedit, tmpButton) > 0 Then
            Dim lineSplited = lineToedit.Split
            Dim cnt As Integer = lineSplited.Count
            Dim newVal = addCount(CInt(lineSplited.Last()))

            lineSplited(cnt - 1) = newVal
            lineToedit = String.Join(" ", lineSplited)
            line(f) = lineToedit
        End If
        f = f + 1
    Next

    strbild = New StringBuilder
    'putting together all the reversed word
    For j = 0 To line.GetUpperBound(0)
        strbild.Append(line(j))
        strbild.Append(vbNewLine)
    Next

    ' writing to original file
    File.WriteAllText(pathAndFile, strbild.ToString())

    Me.Refresh()

End Sub

' Reverse Function
Public Function ReverseString(ByRef strToReverse As String) As String
    Dim result As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To strToReverse.Length - 1
        result += strToReverse(strToReverse.Length - 1 - i)
    Next
    Return result
End Function

Public Function addCount(ByVal arr As Integer) As Integer
    Return arr + 1
End Function

End Class
```

Output in myfile.txt
Button1 = 9
Button2 = 2
Button3 = 4
Button4 = 0
Button5 = 20

Comment: This one is working flawlessly! You are going to make him a happy camper. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can optimize a lot .. this is just a test :) Have Fun !

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a vb winform Application
2. Drag on your form 5 buttons (Button1, Button2, ... etc)
3. copy that :

Imports System.IO.File
Imports System.IO.Path
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

```
 Public Class Form1

Dim line() As String
Dim strbild As StringBuilder
Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim pathAndFile As String
Dim addLine As System.IO.StreamWriter

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim fileName As String = "myfile.txt"
    Dim appPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    pathAndFile = Path.Combine(appPath, fileName)

    If System.IO.File.Exists(pathAndFile) Then
        line = File.ReadAllLines(pathAndFile)

    Else
        Dim addLineToFile = System.IO.File.CreateText(pathAndFile)      'Create an empty txt file
        Dim countButtons As Integer = 5                         'add lines with your desired number of buttons
        For i = 1 To countButtons
            addLineToFile.Write("Button" & i & " = 0" & vbNewLine)
        Next

        addLineToFile.Dispose()                                       '  and close file
    End If



End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    writeToFile(1)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    writeToFile(2)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    writeToFile(3)
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    writeToFile(4)
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    writeToFile(5)
End Sub

Public Sub writeToFile(buttonId As Integer)
    Dim tmpButton As String = "Button" & buttonId
    strbild = New StringBuilder

    line = File.ReadAllLines(pathAndFile)
    i = 0
    For Each lineToedit As String In line

        If lineToedit.Contains(tmpButton) Then
            Dim lineSplited = lineToedit.Split
            Dim newVal = addCount(CInt(lineSplited.Last()))
            'lineToedit.Replace(lineSplited.Last, newVal)
            lineToedit = lineToedit.Replace(lineToedit.Last, newVal)
            line(i) = lineToedit

        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next

    strbild = New StringBuilder
    'putting together all the reversed word
    For j = 0 To line.GetUpperBound(0)
        strbild.Append(line(j))
        strbild.Append(vbNewLine)
    Next

    ' writing to original file
    File.WriteAllText(pathAndFile, strbild.ToString())


End Sub

' Reverse Function
Public Function ReverseString(ByRef strToReverse As String) As String
    Dim result As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To strToReverse.Length - 1
        result += strToReverse(strToReverse.Length - 1 - i)
    Next
    Return result
End Function

Public Function addCount(ByVal arr As Integer) As Integer
    Return arr + 1
End Function

End Class
```

Have fun ! :)
CristiC777

Comment: Nice, it works, but has a bug in it. If you click each button once, the resault will be
Button1 = 1
Button2 = 1
Button3 = 1
Button4 = 1
Button5 = 1

but if you go over the buttons once more (click them a second time) the resault will be
Button6 = 6
Button2 = 2
Button3 = 2
Button4 = 2
Button5 = 2

this will continue untill all buttons are Button6 with value of 6 and the counter wont update if the value is 6.

Comment: Im running VS 2013 community version if that would make any difference?

Comment: Button1 = 1
Button2 = 2
Button3 = 2
Button4 = 1
Button5 = 3
All works ok on my computer .. check your code again

Comment: I'm running in VS2012 Ultimate

Comment: Strange, i copy pasted your code without alterations i'll get back to you!

Comment: I hope you understand the ideea.. now you can adapt on what you want :)

Comment: this behavior seems >>  If lineToedit.Contains(tmpButton) Then is true All time ..

Answer (score 0):

try this on vs2013
**change If confition**

```
line = File.ReadAllLines(pathAndFile)
    i = 0
    For Each lineToedit As String In line
        If InStr(1, lineToedit, tmpButton) > 0 Then
            'If lineToedit.Contains(tmpButton) = True Then
            Dim lineSplited = lineToedit.Split
            Dim newVal = addCount(CInt(lineSplited.Last()))

            lineToedit = lineToedit.Replace(lineToedit.Last, newVal)
            line(i) = lineToedit
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
```

Comment: It's so strange, the code gives me these results after clicking the boxes Button6 = 6
Button6 = 6
Button6 = 6
Button4 = 4
Button5 = 4 it's clicked 4 times on each box

Comment: did you changed the IF condition ?

Comment: Yep, i did a rebuild to be sure it was OK and it still does this strange thing, after a couple of clicks the button turns to Button6 and value 6 and then it's stuck

Comment: also put a BreackPoint on that If to see tmpButton value !

Comment: Delete the file by hand from Debug

Comment: Yah ! I get the error .. Button6=6 I will see what :))

Comment: When i hit button 1 first time value is 0 Button1=0 then it adds +1 and next push of button1 the lineToedit turns to Button2=1 and adds +1 And next push of button1 lineToedit is Button3=2 and so on untill Button 6 = 6 is met, then it wont add more to the value. tmpButton is always Button1 though. That never changes.

Comment: ok I'm at work, and I can't focus on this .. check new ver ;)